# Wingware Python IDE: How do I change from Python 2.7.10 to the latest version?

Tags: python, ide, version

How do I change from Python 2.7.10 to the latest version in Wingware Python IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Install latest Python. Go to your Project menu and Project Properties. Change the Python Executable to use Python 3.5 or whatever. Press OK. You might need to restart Wing's Python Shell, but other than that, you should be set.

If you want all projects to default to the latest, you will have to set up your OS to default to the latest Python. Depending on the OS, you may have to fiddle around in some settings dialogs or just uninstall the old version. However, be careful when uninstalling Python on Linux as if you happen to uninstall the system Python, your OS may become non-functional.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give this a shot.